# php html table query

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, html-table

I've been at this for quite some time and just can't figure it out.I have a html table and have to find the total sum of the values in the $total/Sale Cost (last) row. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction.

Code below:

```
<?php

print ("<table border=1><tr><th>Sale Number</th><th>Item</th><th>Item Cost</th><th>Units Sold</th><th>Sale Cost</th></tr>");

    for($x=0; $x<=20; $x=$x+1) {

        /*
        $sofa_total = 0;
        $table_total = 0;
        $chair_total = 0;
        $box_total = 0;
        $tablecloth_total = 0;
        */

        $amount = rand(1,10);
        $res = rand(1, 5);
        $object = 0;
        $total = $amount * $cost;




                if ($res == 1) {
                            $cost = 235.00;
                            $item = "sofa";
                            }
                        elseif ($res == 2) {
                            $cost = 125.00;
                            $item = "table";
                                }
                        elseif ($res == 3) {
                            $cost = 25.99;
                            $item = "chair";
                                }
                        elseif ($res == 4) {
                            $cost = 15.25;
                            $item = "box";
                                }
                        elseif ($res == 5) {
                            $cost = 23.50;
                            $item = "tablecloth";
                                }

        print ("<tr>");
             print ("<td>" . $table[$x][0] = $x+1 . "</td>");
             print ("<td>" . $table[$x][1] = $item . "</td>");
             print ("<td>" . $table[$x][2] = $cost . "</td>");
             print ("<td>" . $table[$x][3] = $amount . "</td>");
             print ("<td>" . $table[$x][4] = $total  . "</td>");
             }
        print ("</tr>");

                if ($object==0) {

                    $sofa_total = $sofa_total + $amount;

                    } elseif ($object==1) {

                    $table_total = $table_total + $amount;

                    } elseif ($object==2) {

                    $chair_total = $chair_total + $amount;

                    } elseif ($object==3) {

                    $box_total = $box_total + $amount;

                    } elseif ($object==4) {

                    $tablecloth_total = $tablecloth_total + $amount;

                    }


print ("</table>"); 

?>
```

Comment: When I try your code I get two errors:

    Notice: Undefined variable: cost ... line 18

    Notice: Undefined variable: sofa_total ... on line 55 -

Maybe try fixing those first? :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess... the table is full of `1`s?

When you print the `<td>`s you should pass in a value, not an espression. The expressions are evaluated and, in your case, return 1 because they are successful (they are assignments).

Rather than taking this approach, you could either keep counters and add them up at every cycle, in  another statement print the current value, and finally echo (print) the counters at the last cycle.

Answer (score 0):

loop things thru.. by adding the values of the current instance to the previous..

```
for( your loop){
    $sampleCost = $sampleCost + $currentCost;
}
echo $sampleCost; /*another way of displaying item*/
```

The idea is to continuously add the value. make sure you consider data, especially the ones with decimal.

```
$currentCost; /* value from the query*/
```